# Not able to click or select the value

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am stuck with the below scenario, trying to click or select the value from the field.

There are 2 fields "Type of Test" which is a dropdown, after selecting the value from dropdown "Body Part" field gets active.

Trying to select the value from "Body Part", but not able to click or select the value from the field.

I have exported the script from Selenium IDE, please let me know where to correct.

```
public class test {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://nyrp.opendr.com/search/client-search/pid/VFZSRk5FNVJQVDA9?script=javascript&badge=1";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "search/client-search/pid/VFZSRk5FNVJQVDA9?script=javascript&badge=1");
    driver.findElement(By.id("typeoftest_1")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("typeoftest_1"))).selectByVisibleText("MRA");
    Thread.sleep(500);


    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.id("bodypart_1"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("bodypart_1")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#bodyPartList_1 > li > div.mailval.")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.search")).click();

  }

private boolean isElementPresent(By id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

Following is the HTML CODE for "Body Part" field:

```
                <div id="bodypart_box_1">
                    <div style="position:absolute;left:185px;z-index: 20">
                        <ul class="parent">
                            <li>
                                <div id="main" class="mailval">events=Object { click=[1]}handle=function()
                                    <input id="bodypart_1" class="bodypart" type="text" onfocus="if($(this).hasClass('disabled')){$(this).blur();}" readonly="readonly" value="Select One" name="bodypart_1" title="">
                                    <input id="actualBodypart_1" type="hidden" value="" name="actualBodypart_1">
                                </div>
                        <ul id="bodyPartList_1" class="top sub bodyPartList" style="display: none;">olddisplay="none"
                            <li>
                                <div class="mailval " title="Head" originaltitle="Head">Head</div>events=Object { click=[1], mouseover=[1]}handle=function()
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="mailval " title="Neck" originaltitle="Neck">Neck</div>events=Object { click=[1], mouseover=[1]}handle=function()
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="mailval " title="Pelvis" originaltitle="Pelvis">Pelvis</div>events=Object { click=[1], mouseover=[1]}handle=function()
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you please show us the HTML you're trying to manipulate?

Comment: Added HTML code for second field